# Reading javascript output from webpage repeatedly

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup, htmlunit

I want to write a java program to read data for a race from [a webpage](http://results.racetimingsolutions.com/MyResults.aspx?uid=16387-6214-1-45819) that gets updated with live results. The webpage contains Javascript code that I believe writes lap times to a table as they are logged. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.

Right now my understanding is that I can get the data using HTMLUnit or JSoup or some combination thereof to read the website as a string and parse the data, but my understanding is that I would need to reload the webpage extremely frequently to get the results as they are uploaded, which will consume a lot of bandwidth and be very CPU intensive. Is it possible to connect directly to the server in some way to get the raw data as it is uploaded rather than read the whole webpage, or is there a better way to do repeatedly read a webpage?

Comment: That depends on if you have access to the server/website backend.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't in this case. But if I did have access what could I do?

Comment: If you had access you could just query directly to the database and get the results you want. How often would you want to check that page for information?

Comment: Is the data on this page update without reloading or you have to reload the website to see update?

Comment: @Mark Obviously I don't want to crash the server by querying too frequently, but I'm thinking once every 3 seconds is necessary to remain suitably up to date.

Comment: @Konowy I've never seen the target page in action, but the javascript code doesn't suggest that the page reloads itself. Assuming the page updates without reloading, what can I do? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that nothing better than making get request every x miliseconds.